# Reading from a Kafka topic and then processing the dataframe and output the batches of data in console

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-kafka

Hi I am trying to read stream of data from a Kafka topic and then preprocessing the same and then outputting it to console. I am using pyspark on AWS EMR. The code is as follows.

### Code

```
df_orders=df_orders.withColumn("date_time",concat(col("date"),lit(" "),col("hours"),lit(":"),col("minutes")))
df_orders_per_minute_calview=df_orders.groupBy(col("date_time")).agg(sum(col("quantity")))

df_orders=df_orders.join(df_orders_per_minute_calview,on="date_time",how="inner")

df_orders=df_orders.drop("hours","minutes","date")
```

### 1) First calculated view for orders per minute calculation at a per minute interval to see the trends of data

```
df_orders=df_orders.withColumn("orders_per_minute_rate",round((col("sum(quantity)"))/(lit(60)),2))  


order_query_console = order_extended_stream \
       .select("invoice_no", "country", "timestamp","type","total_items","total_cost","is_order","is_return") \
       .writeStream \
       .outputMode("append") \
       .format("console") \
       .option("truncate", "false") \
       .trigger(processingTime="1 minute") \
       .start()


order_query_console.awaitTermination()
```

The problem I am getting is spark streaming does not let me  use outputMode=append as I am using aggregation on my dataframe to create a new dataframe and then joining the same with the older dafaframe.Also complete mode is not working.

I need a suggestion weather to use another kafka topic to process this or use watermark.Will that suffice?